# How to replace strings in files but not match a string but not if it contains a substring in powershell? (regex)

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

In Powershell, I'm trying to replace connection string configurations, but need to do two different replaces.

Specifically, I'm trying to replace the user id portion of the connection string but we sometimes use different user id's that need to be replaced differently.

**Example connection strings:**

```
Server=Machine;Database=db;uid=user1;pwd=pass;

Server=Machine2;Database=db2;uid=user1_abc;pwd=pass;
```

1) What would a regex replace string be to only replace the uid when the user doesn't have _abc in the user id?

2) And the reverse of that how to replace only the one that does have _abc?

This for example matches both which won't work:

```
$string -replace "uid=[^;]*" "uid=$myuser"
```

3) The third issue would be how to differentiate the pwd's for only the users with _abc vs only without the _abc ?

I've tried variations of suggested partial word exclusions but none seem to work as expected.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? It looks like you're changing connection strings in a .NET configuration file pre-deploy. Is this in a web.config? The machine.config? .NET has an API for changing these values which might be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To match a user without _abc:

```
uid=(.*(?<!_abc));p
```

`?<!` is a negative lookbehind assertion.  That is, it matches on what is behind it.

2) To match user with _abc:

```
uid=(.*_abc);p
```

3) You would differentiate what password to use in the same way you replace the uid.  Something like this:

```
$string -replace "uid=(.*(?<!_abc));pwd=(.*);" "uid=$myuser;pwd=$pw;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch with some RegEx Lookbehind assertions:

```
$ConStrings = Switch -regex ($ConStrings){
    "uid=[^;]*?(?<!_abc);pwd=" {$_ -replace "uid=[^;]*?(?<!_abc);pwd=", "uid=$NonABCUser;pwd="}
    "uid=[^;]*?(?<=_abc);pwd=" {$_ -replace "uid=[^;]*?(?<=_abc);pwd=", "uid=$ABCUser;pwd="}
}
```

The first line matches if they do not have the _abc immediately before ;pwd, and the second line matches only if they do have it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a complicated regex, another option would be to parse the connection string using `System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder`:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data")
$conn = new-object System.Data.Commmon.DbConnectionStringBuilder
# need to use the method rather than the property since it implements IDictionary
$conn.set_ConnectionString("Server=Machine;Database=db;uid=user1;pwd=pass;")
if ($conn.uid -like "*_abc") {
    $conn.uid = $myuser
}
elseif ($conn.uid -notlike "*_abc" -and $conn.pwd -match "\d+") {
    # Do something leave out the elseif clause.
}

$connectionString = $conn.ConnectionString
```

The `-like` operator is used to match any uid that ends with _abc using wildcards. There is a complementary `-notlike` operator. There are also `-match` and `-notmatch` operators for full regex matching.